# Dynamics 365: Creating a custom Web app UI

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

When creating a App, is there a way to create a custom gui instead of using the forms from entities in a solution? i dont like the limitations of these forms and want to build my own.

Answer (score 1):

you can hide all fields in the form, and add script that customize the UI like [KendoUI](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Create-a-quick-and-easy-8ec3a2f3)

you can also [embed an iframe into a form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/use-iframe-and-web-resource-controls-on-a-form)